# Python - Telebot. Как сделать столбиковые сообщения

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

```
Не нравится окружение?

Дико надоели скучные друзья, жадный работодатель, сварливая жена?

Есть выход! Меняйся!

Когда меняешься ты , меняется твое окружение.
```

Типа такого. Как засунуть такой столбик в str переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если эти строки написаны в массив то так:

```
"\n".join(arr)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @MagicLake если ответ помог то примите его(галочка слева от ответа)

Comment: Привет. Давай я тебе быстро расскажу о моих возможностях:
/help - помощь.
/makelobby - создать лобби.
/findlobby = найти существуещее лобби.
Работает! Ты лучший!!